# Como faço para aparecer botões em cima da minha div?

Tags: html, css

Boa tarde, eu tenho uma div feita com bootstrap e css e quero que quando passar o mouse em cima, apareça dois botões bem no meio dessa div. A minha ideia mesmo é a seguinte, eu tenho várias divs que contém artigos e quando passar o mouse em cima tem que aparecer dois botões, um para editar o artigo e outro para excluir.

Não consigo por nada fazer isso, não sou muito bom com css e os tutoriais que eu acho nenhum é específico para isso e muitos usam divs com position absolute e isso buga tudo minha página.

O HTML da página está assim:

```
<?php include_once './template/header.php'; ?>
<div class="container col-md-12 col-xs-12" id="artigos" style="padding-top: 10px">
    <a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo" id="artigo" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-left: -10px">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo 
                    utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os 
                    embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de t...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo" style="margin-right: 5px">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo 
                    utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os 
                    embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de t...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo 
                    utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os 
                    embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de t...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-left: -10px">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo 
                    utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os 
                    embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de t...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo" style="margin-right: 5px">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo 
                    utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os 
                    embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de t...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo 
                    utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os 
                    embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de t...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-left: -10px">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo 
                    utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os 
                    embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de t...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo" style="margin-right: 5px">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo 
                    utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os 
                    embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de t...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo 
                    utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os 
                    embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de t...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<?php include_once './template/footer.php'; ?>
```

São vários artigos de exemplo que quero que apareçam na página e todos com o efeito de aparecer o botão na frente.

Muito do css é do bootstrap, mas tem um pouco feito por mim também:

```
.panel-artigo:hover{  
    color: #333;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #adadad;
}
```

Imagem de como está minha página:
[image: Imagem de como está minha página]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar algo assim:

```
.panel-artigo {
    position:relative; //Importante para que os botões estejam centralizados
}
.meus-botoes {
    display:none; //garante que o botão não apareça na tela
    margin:0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.panel-artigo:hover .meus-botoes {
    display:block; //Exibe os botões somente com o hover
}
```

E o seu html:

```
<a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo">
        <div class="meus-botoes">
            <!-- insira o html dos botoes aqui -->
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="panel-header">
                <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
            </div>
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo 
                utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os 
                embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de t...
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Seria isso?

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado!

Answer (score 2):

> Como você já possui uma resposta com css, postarei uma utilizando jQuery apenas para possuir outra forma de fazer.

Primeiro vamos criar os botões em cada `div`, dessa forma:

```
<div class="divButton" id="">    
       <button class="btn-primary">Olá</button>
</div>
```

Note que a `div` possui a classe `divButton`. Elá é responsável por deixar o botão escondido (`display: none`) e está fazendo o alinhamento, que você deverá adequar para a forma que desejar. Essa classe está da seguinte forma:

```
.divButton{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
     margin-top: 20%;
    text-align: center;  
    display: none; 
}
```

Agora que já possuímos o botão no lugar e escondido, vamos apenas mostrar os mesmos com jQuery.

```
$('.panel-artigo').mouseenter(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('.divHide, .divButton').fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('.divHide, .divButton').fadeOut();
});
```

Esse código é responsável para mostrar e esconder os botões ao passar o mouse pela `div`.

Seu código completo ficaria assim:

```js
$('.panel-artigo').mouseenter(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('.divHide, .divButton').fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('.divHide, .divButton').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.panel-artigo:hover{  
    color: #333;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #adadad;
}

.divButton{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
     margin-top: 20%;
    text-align: center;  
    display: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container col-md-12 col-xs-12" id="artigos" style="padding-top: 10px">
    <a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo" id="artigo" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-left: -10px">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
                 Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
                </p>
                 <div class="divButton" id="">    
                    <button class="btn-primary">Olá</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo" style="margin-right: 5px">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
              Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
                </p>
                 <div class="divButton" id="">      
                    <button class="btn-primary">Olá</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
           Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
                </p>
                <div class="divButton" id="">    
                    <button class="btn-primary">Olá</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-left: -10px">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
                Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
                </p>
                <div class="divButton" id="">    
                    <button class="btn-primary">Olá</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo" style="margin-right: 5px">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
                 Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
                </p>
                 <div class="divButton" id="">      
                    <button class="btn-primary">Olá</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
 Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
                </p>
                 <div class="divButton" id="">      
                    <button class="btn-primary">Olá</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-left: -10px">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
        Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
                </p>
                 <div class="divButton" id="">       
                    <button class="btn-primary">Olá</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo" style="margin-right: 5px">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
               Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
                </p>
                <div class="divButton" id="">      
                    <button class="btn-primary">Olá</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
                 Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
                </p>
                 <div class="divButton" id="">       
                    <button class="btn-primary">Olá</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Segue um [Exemplo no JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/randrade/2e75rffa/2/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

> Aproveitando as duas boas resposta acima coloquei um código para
>   completar as resposta de como você pode pegar os valores dos botoes para saber qual artigo esta editando

Obs: O laço de repetição for e apenas para exemplificar pois eu creio que esses artigos vem do banco de dados, no lugar do for você pode percorrer o array de artigos do banco e no lugar do valor dos botões você coloca o id ou código deles.

Eu fiz em c#, ai é só mudar para php.

```
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<style>       
     .panel-artigo {
        position: relative;           
    }

    .meus-botoes {   
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('mouseenter', '.minhaDiv', function () {
            $(this).find(":button").show();

        }).on('mouseleave', '.minhaDiv', function () {
            $(this).find(":button").hide();
        });


        $(".Gravar").click(function (e) {
            alert($(this).attr("value"));
        });

        $(".Deletar").click(function (e) {
            alert($(this).attr("value"));
        });
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div class="container col-md-12 col-xs-12" id="artigos" style="padding-top: 10px">

        <% for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {%>

        <div class="minhaDiv">
            <a href="#" style="display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #000">
                <div class="panel panel-default col-md-4 panel-artigo">
                    <div class="meus-botoes">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success Gravar" style="display: none;" value="<%=i%>">Gravar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger Deletar" style="display: none;" value="<%=i%>">Deletar</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="panel-header">
                            <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Titulo 1</h1>
                        </div>
                        <p>
                            Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo 
                                utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os 
                                embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de t...
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>

        </div>

        <%  } %>
    </div>
</form>
```